# Why my javascript looping return error missing 'of ' after for

Tags: javascript, ajax, for-loop

```
dataPoints: [
    for(i = 0;i<json.data.length;i++){
    { label: json.data[i][1], y: parseInt(json.data[i][2])}
    }]
```

I have code like that but I see an error on the console

> SyntaxError: missing 'of' after for

Does anyone know why? I did search on Google, but nothing can tell me why.

Comment: `for` is a _statement_. Object property must be an _expression_.

Comment: @hindmost ya ? thanks I don't know that

Comment: It is not allowed to put statements such as `for` between the `[` and `]` signs, only values or expressions, like this: `[ { label: 'A', y: parseInt('3') }, { label: 'B', y: 4 } ]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, You will get incorrect syntax. Seems you want to create an array so use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
dataPoints: json.data.map(function (d) {
    return {
        label: d[1],
        y: parseInt(d[2])
    }
})
```